# websockets "not understood" error

Tags: php, websocket

When i run my code and type in (hello) or (hi) the Client is disconnected and i get this error from the server:

```
��r�W� not understood
```

This is my Server's code:

```
#!/php -q
<?php  /*  >php -q server.php  */

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$master  = WebSocket("localhost",12345);
$sockets = array($master);
$users   = array();
$debug   = false;

while(true){
  $changed = $sockets;
 $write = NULL;
$except = NULL; 

socket_select($changed, $write, $except, NULL);

  foreach($changed as $socket){
    if($socket==$master){
      $client=socket_accept($master);
      if($client<0){ console("socket_accept() failed"); continue; }
      else{ connect($client); }
    }
    else{
      $bytes = @socket_recv($socket,$buffer,2048,0);
      if($bytes==0){ disconnect($socket); }
      else{
        $user = getuserbysocket($socket);
        if(!$user->handshake){ dohandshake($user,$buffer); }
        else{ process($user,$buffer); }
      }
    }
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
function process($user,$msg){
  $action = unwrap($msg);
  say("< ".$action);
  switch($action){
    case "hello" : send($user->socket,"hello human");                       break;
    case "hi"    : send($user->socket,"zup human");                         break;
    case "name"  : send($user->socket,"my name is Multivac, silly I know"); break;
    case "age"   : send($user->socket,"I am older than time itself");       break;
    case "date"  : send($user->socket,"today is ".date("Y.m.d"));           break;
    case "time"  : send($user->socket,"server time is ".date("H:i:s"));     break;
    case "thanks": send($user->socket,"you're welcome");                    break;
    case "bye"   : send($user->socket,"bye");                               break;
    default      : send($user->socket,$action." not understood");           break;
  }
}

function send($client,$msg){
  say("> ".$msg);
  $msg = wrap($msg);
  socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
}

function WebSocket($address,$port){
  $master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");
  socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  or die("socket_option() failed");
  socket_bind($master, $address, $port)                    or die("socket_bind() failed");
  socket_listen($master,20)                                or die("socket_listen() failed");
  echo "Server Started : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
  echo "Master socket  : ".$master."\n";
  echo "Listening on   : ".$address." port ".$port."\n\n";
  return $master;
}

function connect($socket){
  global $sockets,$users;
  $user = new User();
  $user->id = uniqid();
  $user->socket = $socket;
  array_push($users,$user);
  array_push($sockets,$socket);
  console($socket." CONNECTED!");
}

function disconnect($socket){
  global $sockets,$users;
  $found=null;
  $n=count($users);
  for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    if($users[$i]->socket==$socket){ $found=$i; break; }
  }
  if(!is_null($found)){ array_splice($users,$found,1); }
  $index = array_search($socket,$sockets);
  socket_close($socket);
  console($socket." DISCONNECTED!");
  if($index>=0){ array_splice($sockets,$index,1); }
}
function dohandshake($user, $buffer) {
$key = null;

console("\nRequesting handshake...");
console($buffer);
console("Handshaking...");

preg_match("#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*?)\r\n#", $buffer, $match) && $key = $match[1];

$key .= "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
$key = sha1($key);
$key = pack('H*', $key);
$key = base64_encode($key);

$upgrade =
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$key}\r\n\r\n";

socket_write($user->socket, $upgrade . chr(0), strlen($upgrade . chr(0)));
$user->handshake = true;
console($upgrade);
console("Done handshaking...");
return true;
}

function getheaders($header) {
$retVal = array();
$fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match)) {
        $match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
        if (isset($retVal[$match[1]])) {
            $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
        } else {
            $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
        }
    }
}

if (preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/", $header, $match)) {
    $retVal['GET'] = $match[1];
}
return $retVal;
}
function getuserbysocket($socket){
  global $users;
  $found=null;
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->socket==$socket){ $found=$user; break; }
  }
  return $found;
}

function     say($msg=""){ echo $msg."\n"; }
function    wrap($msg=""){ return chr(0).$msg.chr(255); }
function  unwrap($msg=""){ return substr($msg,1,strlen($msg)-2); }
function console($msg=""){ global $debug; if($debug){ echo $msg."\n"; } }

class User{
  var $id;
  var $socket;
  var $handshake;
}

?>
```

This is how it looks on the Client's side:

```
WebSocket - status 0
Welcome - status 1
Sent: hi
Disconnected - status 3
```

Comment: I think your problem is on line 15. ;) Look up passing by reference in php.

Comment: I know it's on line 15, that's why i included it in my question -_- how can i fix it now ?

Comment: satish rajak's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29412105/1364007) looks promising. You can't pass `null` by value because it's not a value type. I found [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) about passing by reference on php.net while I was looking for information to answer your question.

Comment: @WaiHaLee i like your apprisation

Comment: same problem after i tried Rajak's solution, it just gives the error more frequent.

Comment: Hmm. Have a look at the signature for `socket_select ` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php): `int socket_select ( array &$read , array &$write , array &$except , int $tv_sec [, int $tv_usec = 0 ] )`. You can **only** pass null by reference. This is all I know.

Comment: please post your whole code

Comment: i need your php code

Comment: @WaiHaLee   Guys i solved the problem but i got another one, i updated the problem description up above, please take a look.

Comment: @satishrajak i solved the problem but i got another one, i updated the problem description up above, please take a look.

Comment: @0black0rain you probably should have asked a *new* question rather than completely changing the current one, as you've invalidated the existing answers. Also, it's probably not worth asking me as I don't know any php.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I couldn't, since i have to wait 90 minutes, and I'm way behind schedule, since errors have been popping like crazy, since I started doing this. Thank you anyway

Comment: No problem. I wasn't aware of a restriction on question asking. Good luck.

Comment: use this before while loop socket_set_nonblock ($sockets);

Comment: @satishrajak Thank you for the help, it's still not working, can we please continue here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413748/websockets-not-understood-error

Comment: @satishrajak i got the same error and it also gave me this warning


 PHP Warning:  socket_set_nonblock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /var/www/html/mysite/Server.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

I have to declare $write and $except first

```
 $write = NULL;
$except = NULL; 

socket_select($changed, $write, $except, NULL);
```

Then it works.