# websockets not understood Error

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

When i run my code and type in (hello) or (hi) the Client is disconnected and i get this error from the server:

```
��r�W� not understood
```

This is my Server's code:

```
#!/php -q
<?php  /*  >php -q server.php  */

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$master  = WebSocket("localhost",12345);
$sockets = array($master);
$users   = array();
$debug   = false;

while(true){
  $changed = $sockets;
 $write = NULL;
$except = NULL; 

socket_select($changed, $write, $except, NULL);

  foreach($changed as $socket){
    if($socket==$master){
      $client=socket_accept($master);
      if($client<0){ console("socket_accept() failed"); continue; }
      else{ connect($client); }
    }
    else{
      $bytes = @socket_recv($socket,$buffer,2048,0);
      if($bytes==0){ disconnect($socket); }
      else{
        $user = getuserbysocket($socket);
        if(!$user->handshake){ dohandshake($user,$buffer); }
        else{ process($user,$buffer); }
      }
    }
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
function process($user,$msg){
  $action = unwrap($msg);
  say("< ".$action);
  switch($action){
    case "hello" : send($user->socket,"hello human");                       break;
    case "hi"    : send($user->socket,"zup human");                         break;
    case "name"  : send($user->socket,"my name is Multivac, silly I know"); break;
    case "age"   : send($user->socket,"I am older than time itself");       break;
    case "date"  : send($user->socket,"today is ".date("Y.m.d"));           break;
    case "time"  : send($user->socket,"server time is ".date("H:i:s"));     break;
    case "thanks": send($user->socket,"you're welcome");                    break;
    case "bye"   : send($user->socket,"bye");                               break;
    default      : send($user->socket,$action." not understood");           break;
  }
}

function send($client,$msg){
  say("> ".$msg);
  $msg = wrap($msg);
  socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
}

function WebSocket($address,$port){
  $master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");
  socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  or die("socket_option() failed");
  socket_bind($master, $address, $port)                    or die("socket_bind() failed");
  socket_listen($master,20)                                or die("socket_listen() failed");
  echo "Server Started : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
  echo "Master socket  : ".$master."\n";
  echo "Listening on   : ".$address." port ".$port."\n\n";
  return $master;
}

function connect($socket){
  global $sockets,$users;
  $user = new User();
  $user->id = uniqid();
  $user->socket = $socket;
  array_push($users,$user);
  array_push($sockets,$socket);
  console($socket." CONNECTED!");
}

function disconnect($socket){
  global $sockets,$users;
  $found=null;
  $n=count($users);
  for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    if($users[$i]->socket==$socket){ $found=$i; break; }
  }
  if(!is_null($found)){ array_splice($users,$found,1); }
  $index = array_search($socket,$sockets);
  socket_close($socket);
  console($socket." DISCONNECTED!");
  if($index>=0){ array_splice($sockets,$index,1); }
}
function dohandshake($user, $buffer) {
$key = null;

console("\nRequesting handshake...");
console($buffer);
console("Handshaking...");

preg_match("#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*?)\r\n#", $buffer, $match) && $key = $match[1];

$key .= "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
$key = sha1($key);
$key = pack('H*', $key);
$key = base64_encode($key);

$upgrade =
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$key}\r\n\r\n";

socket_write($user->socket, $upgrade . chr(0), strlen($upgrade . chr(0)));
$user->handshake = true;
console($upgrade);
console("Done handshaking...");
return true;
}

function getheaders($header) {
$retVal = array();
$fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match)) {
        $match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
        if (isset($retVal[$match[1]])) {
            $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
        } else {
            $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
        }
    }
}

if (preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/", $header, $match)) {
    $retVal['GET'] = $match[1];
}
return $retVal;
}
function getuserbysocket($socket){
  global $users;
  $found=null;
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->socket==$socket){ $found=$user; break; }
  }
  return $found;
}

function     say($msg=""){ echo $msg."\n"; }
function    wrap($msg=""){ return chr(0).$msg.chr(255); }
function  unwrap($msg=""){ return substr($msg,1,strlen($msg)-2); }
function console($msg=""){ global $debug; if($debug){ echo $msg."\n"; } }

class User{
  var $id;
  var $socket;
  var $handshake;
}

?>
```

This is how it looks on the Client's side:

```
WebSocket - status 0
Welcome - status 1
Sent: hi
Disconnected - status 3
```

Can anyone here help ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411968/websockets-not-understood-error

Comment: @andHapp so can you answer the question ?!!!!

Comment: In order to narrow down the issue, try connecting to the WebSocket server from chrome developer tools. Browsers expose the client and it's an easy way to test bugs in your php client. Give that a go. Also, please try to be nice being sarcy doesn't help anyone.